# Case statement order by - invalid column name 'yearmonth'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case

My query doesn't recognize the column when I use a case statement, but does when I don't. I really need to use the case statement. Can you please let me know why it is wrong. Thank you very much.

i will update what i am trying to do thank you

Comment: `then 10 en 'Nov2020' `...

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Can't you simply `ORDER BY SRVC_DT` instead?

Comment: Your computed column will always have a dash (-) between the month and year so the constants in your case expression are all incorrect except the first. You over complicate your logic. And does using "mm" in your datediff function REALLY SAVE you so much effort that you don't use "month" - which is far more readable and far easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, gotcha, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't recognize the column alias when it is in an expression.  Sad.

But there is an easier way:

```
order by min(SRVC_DT)
```

This just orders by the minimum of `SRVC_DT` in each group.

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated, everyone's assistance and advice is much appreciated.

Comment: @Frederica . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept this answer.  It is by far the simplest.

Comment: Only reason, is I am new to this.. I wish I could have given both points,,, didn't want to offend

Comment: I really respect this website.. need to dig in more regarding the point situation.. don't want to get banned or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your **Table Column Name** Instead of using its `yearmonth` **ALIAS NAME**.

**Alias name is just for renaming a table or a column temporarily by giving another name.**

```
SELECT (LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,SRVC_DT),3)  + '-'  + CAST(YEAR(SRVC_DT) AS NCHAR)) AS YEARMONTH
FROM  IRX_MAIN.ESA.VW_CLM_PHRMCY_DLY_MSTR
WHERE DATEDIFF(MM, SRVC_DT, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
ORDER BY (CASE (LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,SRVC_DT),3)  + '-'  + CAST(YEAR(SRVC_DT) AS NCHAR)) WHEN 'JUL-2020'  THEN 7 
                                                                        WHEN 'AUG2020' THEN 8 
                                                                        WHEN 'SEP2020' THEN 9 
                                                                        WHEN 'OCT2020' THEN 10 
                                                                        WHEN 'NOV2020' THEN 11  
                                                                        WHEN 'DEC2020' THEN 12 END)
```

Also, You can try this:

```
SELECT (LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,SRVC_DT),3)  + '-'  + CAST(YEAR(SRVC_DT) AS NCHAR)) AS YEARMONTH
FROM  IRX_MAIN.ESA.VW_CLM_PHRMCY_DLY_MSTR
WHERE DATEDIFF(MM, SRVC_DT, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
ORDER BY SRVC_DT
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. actually it will in a union where sometimes its srvc_dt and sometimes its elig date... i was just testing one at a time.. thank you it should be when and not 'en'

Comment: (select (LEFT(datename(Month,SRVC_DT),3)  + '-'  + cast(year(SRVC_DT) as nchar)) as yearmonth

from  IRX_MAIN.tsa.VW_CLM_PHRMCY

where datediff(mm, SRVC_DT, getdate()) between 1 and 12

union
select (LEFT(datename(Month,SRVC_DT),3)  + '-'  + cast(year(SRVC_DT) as nchar)) as yearmonth

from  IRX_MAIN.tsa.vw_ELIG_PHRMCY

where datediff(mm, elig_DT, getdate()) between 1 and 12)

order by case....

Comment: I also Corrected  when instead of  'en' in my Query. -- @Frederica

Comment: Can you please let me know how to handle it when its not always srvc_dt, but sometimes elig_dt?

Comment: Plz, Explain the Case Clearly - @Frederica